# does anyone know what snake is this? found on my other family home

Tags: snake

pic might be a little dark because it was on night
[image]

thank you very much for your answer

Comment: welcome. For species ID we need the geographical location (country, state) where you found it, and possibly also what time of year it was, temperature and what kind of habitat it might have coming from (is there forest around your home, ore are you way up in the mountains etc)

Comment: Looks like a constrictor, many of which are kept (and released) as pets. So the location my not be an indicator. In any case, it is not venomous.

Answer (score -1):

It is a *Boa constrictor*. Like the comment mentioned, the geographic location helps. If you are in southern Central America or South America, it's probably native; elsewhere, it's probably someone's escaped pet. They are non-venomous, but will defend themselves if they are threatened or harassed by hissing and striking. They have many, small, very sharp teeth that could easily lacerate your skin, but not deeply.

These snakes populations are very, very reduced, so please do not harm it since it does not want to interact with you at all. They eat rodents and other pests, so it's good to keep their numbers up. They are also magnificently beautiful and have *very* interesting biology (for example, they give live birth and have pits on their faces that help them sense infrared!).